# Como puedo reemplazar la columna en MySql, según el usuario logueado.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy construyendo una app móvil como examen de semestre, la cual consta de una BD en MySql con dos tablas; users_ppl como **Tabla 1** y users_extra como **Tabla 2**.

La tabla 1 contiene un usuario principal, el cual tendrá asignado 2 usuarios extras en la tabla 2.

Tanto el usuario principal como el usuario extra, puede acceder a la app, y revisar la información ligada al usuario principal.

Cuando el usuario principal la app muestra su nombre, por ejemplo, si **Julian** en la **tabla 1** se loguea, aparecerá en la app su nombre y demás datos ligados a este. El problema esta en que cuando un **usuario extra como: Juana** en la **tabla 2** que esta ligado a Julian, inicia sesión, no me muestra en la app el nombre de Juana, sino el de Julian.

Como hago para construir adecuadamente el script en PHP, reemplzar las columnas del usuario extra como usuario y token, cuando este usuario inicie sesión, Es decir si Julian inicia sesion traer la columna usuario y token de Julian, y si Juana inicia sesion, traer las columnas usuario y token de Juana.

**Tabla 1** Usuarios principales.

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | direccion | telefono |
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Julian    | *****    | e12A1 |  Av106    | 777 5588 |
----------------------------------------------------------
2  | Marta     | *****    | HJb71 |  Cra57    | 554 1122 |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Tabla 2** Usuarios extras

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | id_ppl |
--------------------------------------------
1  | Juana     | *****    |       | 1      |
--------------------------------------------
2  | Martin    | *****    |       | 1      |
--------------------------------------------
3  | Dora      | *****    |       | 2      |
--------------------------------------------
```

PHP: Como traer los datos del usuario extra en `$stmt->bind_result` y en `$user = array(`

```
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('usuario', 'password'))){

 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $password = md5($_POST['password']); 


$sql="SELECT T1.id, T1.usuario, T1.token, T1.direccion, T1.telefono
FROM users_ppl T1 
LEFT JOIN users_extra T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);     
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario, $password); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){ 
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $usuario, $token,  $direccion, $telefono);
    $stmt->fetch();


$user = array(
 'id' => $id,
 'usuario' => $usuario,
 'token' => $token,
 'direccion' => $direccion,
 'telefono' => $telefono
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Según yo, debiera saltarte un error en

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario, $password);
```

Porque estás intentando bindear dos parámetros a una sentencia SQL que no tiene placeholders.

Pero bueno, suponiendo que tu consulta real **sí tiene placeholders**, entonces podrías hacer algo como:

```
$sql="SELECT id, usuario, token, direccion, telefono
      FROM
       (
        SELECT T1.id, T1.usuario, T1.password, T1.token, T1.direccion, T1.telefono
        FROM users_ppl T1 
          UNION ALL
        SELECT T2.id, T2.usuario, T2.password, T2.token, T1.direccion, T1.telefono
        FROM users_ppl T1 LEFT JOIN users_extra T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl
       ) tabla_union
       WHERE usuario=$1 AND password=$2
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver si este query te funciona:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.usuario, T1.token, T1.direccion, T1.telefono FROM tabla1 t1

UNION

SELECT T2.id, T2.usuario, T2.token, "" as direccion, "" as telefono FROM tabla2 t2
```

Yo modificaria la logica, tiene varias opciones:

1) Crear una sola tabla de usuarios y colocarle dos campos nuevos, uno donde indique la relacion con un usuario de la misma tabla ejemplo "id_usu_padre" puede ser vacio o nulo y el otro donde indique si es principal o extra como un tipo de usuario.

2) Haz un query que busque en la tabla1 y si le haces un count en php y sale 0 ejecutas un query donde busque en la tabla2.

Espero haberte ayudado.